# Controlling back/forward navigation of a *child* iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm working on a simple Javascript-based windows "app" (not a website, just some HTML & JS files all in a single folder that will be used on a local PC).

The startup page is Page1.html. This page contains 2 buttons ("back" and "forward"), and an iframe which displays the content of Page2.html. And Page2.html also contains an iframe, which displays various other pages in the same folder (we'll call these the "color" pages --> Red.html, Green.html, Blue.html, etc).

So in other words, when Page1.html is started up, you're looking at the contents of an iframe inside of an iframe (which would be Red.html, etc.).

So here's what I need to accomplish...

I need to use the back/forward buttons on Page1.html to navigate between the various "color" pages (which are framed inside of Page2.html).

I've found that it's easy to navigate backwards/forwards an iframe that's on the *same page* as the JS that's controlling the iframe, by using something like...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#back_button_on_page1").mousedown(function(){  
        document.getElementById("iframe_on_page1").contentWindow.history.back(); 
    });
    $("#forward_button_on_page1").mousedown(function(){  
        document.getElementById("iframe_on_page1").contentWindow.history.forward(); 
    });
});
```

etc etc.

But that's not what I need. What I need (and can't figure out how to do) is to control an iframe that's on *another* page, like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#back_button_on_page1").mousedown(function(){ 
        document.getElementById("iframe_on_page2").contentWindow.history.back(); 
    });
    $("#forward_button_on_page1").mousedown(function(){   
        document.getElementById("iframe_on_page2").contentWindow.history.forward(); 
    });
});
```

I've put the above JS in a single file (Main.js), and then called that file from both Page1.html and Page2.html (after I included the jQuery libary on each page, of course). But it doesn't work.

So... does anyone know how to accomplish this?

BTW- if it makes any difference, the solution only needs to work in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("iframe_on_page1").contentWindow.document.getElementById("iframe_on_page2").contentWindow.history.back();`?

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work. Thanks anyways.